# Python Pandas Pairwise Frequency Table with many columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, crosstab

Beginner Pandas Question here:

**How do I create a cross frequency count table for all columns?** I want to ues the output to make a seaborn heatmap plot showing the counts between each pair of columns.

I have a dataframe (pulled down from hdfs with pyspark) with ~70 unique columns and about 600K rows

Sample Desired output:

```
    C1 C2 C3 C4 ...C70
C1  -  1  1  2
C2  1  -  0  2
C3  1  0  -  1
C4  2  2  1  -
...   
C70
```

Sample DF:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'C1': [ 0, 2, 5, 0, 3], #...600K
    'C2': [3, 0 , 2, 0, 0],
    'C3': [0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
    'C4': [2, 1, 1, 4, 0]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3','C4'])
print(df)
```

I've tried using crosstab, pivot, pivot_table from pandas and think that the solution is using crosstab, but I can't get it in the desired output format (sorry if there is something obvious I'm missing). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain the logic here ? why c1-c4=2 and c4-c1=1

Comment: My data here is independent documents (rows) submitted to one or more entities (each column). I want to be able to identify which pair (or even groups) of entities receive the most submission. I think a heatmap would be a good way to visualize this (because of many rows and columns) and, form reading the seaborn documentation, need the data in this format (I think).

Comment: Oops - you're right; typo ><.  Desired output should be symmetrical down the diagonal; edited!

Comment: Please have your expected output reflect the sample input posted. Are you looking for `v = df.clip_upper(1); v.T.dot(v)`?

Comment: That was it, thanks! Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clip positive values to `1` with `clip_upper`, and then compute the dot product:

```
i = df.clip_upper(1)
j = i.T.dot(i)
```

```
j

    C1  C2  C3  C4
C1   3   1   1   2
C2   1   2   0   2
C3   1   0   2   1
C4   2   2   1   4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a PySpark DataFrame solution using `spark-sql`. Definitely not as elegant as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's pandas solution, but perhaps this will be useful for really big dataframes.

Suppose you had your data in a PySpark DataFrame `spark_df`.

```
spark_df.show()
#+---+---+---+---+
#| C1| C2| C3| C4|
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  0|  3|  0|  2|
#|  2|  0|  0|  1|
#|  5|  2|  0|  1|
#|  0|  0|  3|  4|
#|  3|  0|  3|  0|
#+---+---+---+---+
```

Create an empty DataFrame to hold the output. The schema for this is going to be one `StringType()` column followed by an `IntegerType()` column for each column in `spark_df`:

```
cols = spark_df.columns
schema = StructType(
    [StructField('col', StringType())] + [StructField(c, IntegerType()) for c in cols]
)
output = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([], schema=schema)
output.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col: string (nullable = true)
# |-- C1: long (nullable = true)
# |-- C2: long (nullable = true)
# |-- C3: long (nullable = true)
# |-- C4: long (nullable = true)
```

Register this DataFrame as a table:

```
spark_df.registerTempTable('table')
```

Iterate through each column in the DataFrame and build a query to get the values for that "row". Add the output of the query to `output` using `union()`.

```
for col in cols:
    q = "SELECT '%s' AS col," % col
    q += ",".join("SUM(CASE WHEN %s > 0 AND %s > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS %s " % (col, c, c) for c in cols)
    q += " FROM table t"
    output = output.union(sqlCtx.sql(q))
```

Finally the output:

```
output.show()
#+---+---+---+---+---+
#|col| C1| C2| C3| C4|
#+---+---+---+---+---+
#| C1|  3|  1|  1|  2|
#| C2|  1|  2|  0|  2|
#| C3|  1|  0|  2|  1|
#| C4|  2|  2|  1|  4|
#+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Which matches the pandas version.

Comment: it may not be as elegant as pandas, but it'll be much faster on those huge data-sets; thanks!

Comment: @whs2k it may be even better to build the whole query inside the for loop, and the do one call to `sqlCtx.sql()` at the end instead of calling `union()` inside of the loop.